# Ruby: How to exit program and ask if user wants to play again

Tags: ruby

This is for a class assignment. We create a Rock Paper Scissors Spock Lizard (RPSSL) game. User vs. computer. The first to win 5x is the grand_winner.

I'm having trouble implementing code to ask user if they would like to play again and if not, break out of the program. This was easy to implement when it was just a single game.

Hints or tips are appreciate above a definitive answer.

I've tried defining a method, putting the code into a condition to check if there is a grand_winner, but I'm really having trouble. I know that I may need to go back or simply slow down because the answer is right there.

Here is the link to github:

https://github.com/emilianolowe/RB101_lesson_two/blob/master/rpssl.rb

I expect the program to ask the user if they would like to play another round. If the user does not want to play another round, exit the program.

Comment: Post the relevant code right here, in the question.

Comment: The whole program? It's about 80 lines, which is why I thought it would be better to include a link.

Comment: The problem with too much code is it's _too much code_, no matter how you include it. And there's an additional problem with external links: they die, rendering posts meaningless. So if you could reduce your code to a [mcve] and post it right here, it'd be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
loop do
  loop do
    # do stuff here
    break if grand_winner
  end
  print "continue? "
  break if gets.strip.downcase == 'no'
end
```

(Note that I'm just chaining the `puts` into my condition, as it always returns nil, so the right-hand-side of the `or` will be evaluated)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I only want this to trigger if there is a grand_winner. The code above would work if I just wanted to "Do stuff here.." one time. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Nano: what you mean, "one time"? This code will loop (and keep doing stutt) until you input "no".

Comment: Okay, now it should do what you want @Nano :)

Comment: Now the internal loop does not `break` I would recommend that `break if grand_winner` be in the inner loop and `break if (print "continue? " or gets.strip.downcase == 'no')` be in the outer loop

Comment: @engineersmnky ah, that's true xD

Answer (score 0):

You can create an if statement based on what the grand_winner function returns. I modified it a bit so it would just return true or false.

```rb
def grand_winner
  if WINS[:user] == 5
    prompt(MESSAGES['user_grand_winner'])
    return true #returns true if user is grand winner
  elsif WINS[:computer] == 5
    prompt(MESSAGES['computer_grand_winner'])
    return false #returns false if COM is grand winner
  end
end
```

So now you can do this:

```rb
if grand_winner == true #so if the grand winner was the player 
  prompt("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)")
  play_again = gets().chomp
  break unless play_again.downcase.start_with?('y')
else 
    #whatever happens if they were not the grand winner
end
```